# PHP Post Values with Lambda

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have set up a HTML form which when submitted will use a PHP post function to then display the values in a specific layout within a text area on another page.

This is currently running on an EC2 web server, although I would like to run this as a static website on S3.

Is it possible to do this using lambda to then display the values therefore not requiring the EC2 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible, In this case, you need to run the whole project in lambda functions.

try with lambda function by adding you `.php` files to lambda and run.

- create a sample lambda function on **php** and write some HelloWorld program.
- attach **API gateway** to that function and allow all types of methods.
- if it works, add one by one and test.

if any queries comment below...:)